# How can I query all userstories in all projects?

Tags: rally

I want to get all userstores regardless their projects. can this be done in one query? 
I have a recursive logic and looping over projects, for each project doing this logic can't work for me as some US have parents in different projects

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is by including workspace=/workspace/12345&project=null as query string parameters in your WSAPI request url.  How are you accessing the WSAPI?  App SDK 1?  2?  There are different ways to do this depending on what toolkit you are using.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. I am usign the java SDK, not the rally app SDK.

Comment: I try it and it didn't work! I got this error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<QueryResult rallyAPIMinor="38" rallyAPIMajor="1"> -<Errors> <OperationResultError>Null project not allowed in this Web Services version.</OperationResultError> </Errors> <Warnings/> <TotalResultCount>0</TotalResultCount> <StartIndex>0</StartIndex> <PageSize>0</PageSize> <Results/> </QueryResult>

Comment: I set project to empty and it works now. I am sure if this what should happen because In version 32 I use rally document that when no project is supplied, the default one will be selected! anyway I see that it give result from all projects not the default user one.

Comment: What is the status of this answer?  I am using v1.41 web services.  project=null fails with an error "Null project not allowed on this Web Services version", and project='' seems to have no effect.  Is this still supported?